# Sorting and selecting from sql table by time zone

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a question which seams to me complicated but for some of you it can be easy. 
Here it is:
I have a MySQL table like this

```
id  |  username  |  time_zone | selected
 1      XXX           +4          1
 2      XXX           -6          0
 3      XXX           NULL        1
```

And so on. The number of rows can be more than a million. (Note that there can be users whose Time Zone is undefined.)
There is a PHP script which runs every hour via cron job and selects an amount of rows from the table.
Now the difficult part.

1. The number of rows selected from the table must be equal for each hour. (`amount selected = COUNT()/24`)
2. Each of the rows must not be selected more than once per day(that's why I have added column "selected" in the table).
3. Every user must be selected when their local time is from 1PM to 5PM.
4. If the user`s time zone is undefined they must be selected from 5PM to 8PM.
5. If the amount of users is not enough for a specific time e.g. user count with time zone +4 is less than `COUNT()/24`, the equality can be compensated with undefined users or with the users from neighbor time zones.
6. If there are to many users for the specified time they can be passed to the next neighbor time zone.

I don`t need the code but the logic. If someone can help I will be very great full. If there are any questions I can go in more details.

Comment: How does the script look currently?

Comment: I have no script yet as I can`t even understand from what to begin. Before I was just selecting from the table by limiting the number of selection by `COUNT()/24` now I added time zones and I`m stuck. And when selecting I was seting the `selected` column to 1 not to select the row twice and at the end of the day everything was being updated to 0

Comment: Are your requirements possible to fulfill if you have 3 or more time zones each with more than COUNT()/24 rows?  Perhaps if you explained why rows should be selected between 1-5pm in their local time zone, someone might be able to suggest a simpler alternative.

Comment: No problem. I have a Facebook application which updates user information. It should be updated when the users' country is most active. So the most active hours for known countries is from 1pm to 5pm. But there are users whose timezone is undefined and for these users I have chosen from 5pm to 8pm as the probability is highest that wherever they are, their countries' active hour will be in that period. And the reason for dividing them in equal portions is the server load as the script working on that users is very heavy.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bin packing problem.  This is made much more complicated by the "borrowing from neighboring timezones".  Here are some ideas on how you can approach the problem.

Here is one way to think about the solution:

1. Add a column "used time zone" into the table (you can re-use `selected` if you want)
2. Randomly choose one user from each time zone among users that haven't been selected
3. Assign it into into the time zone
4. If there are no users for a time zone, then look at neighboring zones for a user
5. Iterate for again for the nth person in each bucket

Oh, this seems complicated.  It also seems like a bunch of cursors would be needed to solve the problem.

Instead, let's populate by time zone instead of user.

1. Start with the most populous available time zone
2. Randomly select available users from the time zone and set their "used time zone" to the time zone
3. If there are not enough users, go to previous time zones and select excess available users.
4. Iterate over the time zones

This is getting close.  You can further optimize it by assigning users to time zones all at once.  Then, for the time zones that are not full, go and pick up excess users from other time zones.